# Multiplication Sums across cells?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Example image of what kind of thing i need]

I know this isn't very professional but i'm very very new to google sheets and spreadsheets in general.

So if I know that Tier 4.3 leather is worth 6 points in the contest, someone brings me 739 of them along with 589 Tier 6.2 ore. 
Is there a way i could type 739 and 589 in the table on the right hand side and set up a formula in some way to allow the sheet to calculate how many points this person earned for that resource? Then i would just manually delete the values once i have a final number and start on the next person.

If anyone has any tips or favourite places to look where i can learn how to do things like this for myself that would also be amazing. I've taken to google but I find the jargon and terms a little daunting!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the function `=sumproduct()`

In your case: `=sumproduct(B3:E18,I3:L18)`

Enter that in an empty cell to the side and your result will appear there when you enter values into the cells on the righthand table.